# Bokehでグラフ移動やズームを同期させずに、グラフ範囲を合わせる方法を教えてください

Tags: python, bokeh

## 環境

- Python 3.6
- Bokeh 0.13.0

## やりたいこと

PythonのBokehというグラフライブラリを使っています。
2つのグラフのプロット範囲を、合わせたいです。

`x_range`,`y_range`オプションで、プロット範囲を合わせることができました。

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_file, show,output_notebook

output_notebook()

p1 = figure()
p1.line([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5])

p2 = figure(x_range=p1.x_range, y_range=p1.y_range)
p2.line([2,3,4],[2,3,4])

show(bokeh.layouts.column(p1,p2))
```

https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/interaction/linking.html 参考

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

しかし、この方法だとグラフの移動やズームも、同期されてしまいます。
グラフの移動やズームは、同期しないようにしたいです。

## 質問

グラフ移動やズームを同期させずに、グラフ範囲を合わせるには、どうすればよいでしょうか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

値を固定で入れてしまうという方法があります。

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, output_notebook, show
from bokeh.layouts import column

output_notebook()

x1, y1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
x_range = min(x1), max(x1)
y_range = min(y1), max(y1)

p1 = figure(x_range=x_range, y_range=y_range)
p1.line(x1, y1)

p2 = figure(x_range=x_range, y_range=y_range)
p2.line([2, 3, 4], [2, 3, 4])

show(column(p1, p2))
```